# ¿Es posible que una aplicación Android actúe en modo HCE y como NFC Reader simultáneamente?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

He desarrollado anteriormente aplicaciones que leen tarjetas y tags NFC y de la misma manera aplicaciones que simulan tarjetas (HCE). Ahora bien, me ha surgido la posible necesidad de hacerlas concurrentes, que la misma aplicación lea y simule ser tarjeta a la vez.

¿Es esto posible?